# Serialization of boost::variant

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11, boost-variant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to serialize a raw boost::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194842/is-it-safe-to-serialize-a-raw-boostvariant)

I would like to serialize a boost::variant type of nonPOD classes.  Would you please tell me if that is possible and show me how to do it?

```
typedef boost::variant<macro,module> mvar
```

Comment: I searched for "Boost serialize variant" on Google and got [this SO answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1196195/734069) Obviously, you'd remove the `enable_if` part for POD types. And your types must be serializable.

Comment: And more precisely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420439/147192

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for your help. Would you please also show me the serialization part?  I was confused. How are we gonna past the archive in?